# Electron/VSCode : Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

I've got a minimal Electron app setup on OSX which works fine when run via command line but I'm unable to use Visual Studio Code to run in debug mode:

```
Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:13207).
```

My launch.json file looks like:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",

            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                ".",
                "--enable-logging"
            ],
            "env": {},
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "sourceMaps": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "address": "localhost",
            "restart": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out [Debugging the Main Process](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process.md)

Comment: add "protocol": "legacy" to config

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, here's a solution.

The version of election I was using did not support --inspect flag, open your package.json in your `devDependencies` options change the `electron` option to the latest release. as of this post "1.7.9"